# Replicate rows of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, replication, repeat

```
df =data.frame ("x"=c(5,4,10,7) , "y"=c (rep (1,2),rep (2,2))
```

I'm trying to replicate each `x`  `y` times and then save it to a variable so the result will be like this:

```
a=c (5,4)
```

then

```
a=c (10,10,7,7)
```

Probably it is an easy one, but I'm new to programming..thanks in advance

Comment: Please try `rep(df$x, df$y)`

Comment: I did try it, but df$y is also considered as factor, so i would like to have separate results for different y. Thank you anyway

Comment: `split(rep(df$x, df$y), rep(df$y, df$y))` should do the trick

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `split` function that creates a list of length distincts values of `y` :

```
split(rep(df$x, df$y), rep(df$y, df$y)) 

$`1`
[1] 5 4

$`2`
[1] 10 10  7  7
```